# Exception by setting a column unique

Tags: 2013, column, unique, exception

I have a huge list, about 200000 items. Till yesterday a custom column called `Nr` was not unique and contained many doubles. Today I cleaned it removing items with double entries, tryied to set the unique contraint to the column but I get an error which says the list contains double values.

In order to find the doubles i wrote a little program:

```
public static void Main()
{
    using (var site = new SPSite("http://sharepointUrlToMyWebsite"))
    {
        var web = site.OpenWeb();
        var list = web.Lists[Guid.Parse("8A680350-F081-42B2-B5D6-7D28526DE40E")];
        var caml = new SPQuery();
        var items = list.GetItems(caml);

        var dic = new Dictionary<int, SPListItem>();
        foreach(SPListItem i in items)
        {
            dic.Add(Convert.ToInt32(i["Nr"]), i);
        }
    }
}
```

If there are doubles it would throw an Exception....it doesn't. So, where are the doubles? I also checked SharePoint recycle bin, there are no items. Could it due to the Searchindex?

Comment: No issues with the 5000 item limit?

Comment: No, I set `$list.EnableThrottling = $false`

Comment: And have you checked both stages of the recycle bin?

Comment: ...i don't know about "stages".

Comment: You have a recycle bin and a second stage recycle bin. I don't know by heart if list items can reside in the second stage, but you might want to check. The second stage is for admins te recover files that are lost from the user's recycle bin.

Comment: I found it and it contains the deleted items. I removed them also from this bin, tried to set the column unique but it still complains about doubles.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that your method LoadItemsFormSP() doesn't return all items. Have you checked the count that's returned from this method to the count in the list.

Comment: I wrote another very simple program and updated my question.